# Invalid outside procedure

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I want to store a path in string "path" which would be available for the whole workbook.

When I do it the following way, I get an error:
"invalid outside procedure"

Here is how I am trying to declare the path in (General) (Declaration)

```
Option Explicit
Dim path As String

 path = "\\sharedDrive\TestFolder\Test_PDF\"
```

I get the error at:

```
"\\sharedDrive\TestFolder\Test_PDF\"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the variable in a module instead, like this:

```
Public path As String
```

Then, in your Workbook_Open routine:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    yourModule.path = "\\sharedDrive\TestFolder\Test_PDF\"
End Sub
```

To access it anywhere, use `yourModule.path`.